# Configure SqlMembershipProvider without password

Tags: asp.net, passwords, sqlmembershipprovider

I need to use the SqlMembershipProvider without password to new users.
How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what you mean - do want users to register with no password, or do you want passwords generated and emailed or something else?

Comment: I need to register a new user with blank password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the SqlMembership provider passwords are required (and this is a good thing). If you really want to have users who don't have passwords (and I'd love to know what scenario needs this) then you will have to use a custom membership provider, and custom login controls, as they all enforce passwords as well.

Comment: The scenario is an internal application. An operator is creating accounts for other users, and the users don't have email to send autogenerated passwords, so I need a blank password, that will be changed on first login